# Bootstrap 4 - Navbar searchbar center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm currently struggling a bit on centring my search bar inside my nav. I've tried many different things, like `mr-atuo` and `ml-auto` or `mx-auto` but I just can't get the element to move. I don't want to use individual pixels because then it will look horrible on mobile.  Here is a small demonstration of where the bar needs to be and where it currently is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDE7d.jpg

Here is the code for my navbar:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/0ba2bca7b4.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light navbar-custom z-depth-half">
    <div class="container">

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-skype"></i>
      </a>

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
       </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Vragen</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Aanbieders</a>
          </li>
        </ul>


        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item" style="border-right: 0.1rem solid lightgrey">
            <form class="form-inline">
              <input class="form-control mr-sm-2 search-input" type="search" placeholder="Zoeken..." name="search" id="search">
              <button class="btn btn-search my-2 my-sm-0 " type="submit">
                 <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
              </button>
            </form>

          </li>



          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Aanmelden</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link btn nav-register-btn" href="">Registreren</a>
          </li>

      
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to change your HTML structure a bit. Move the form out of the UL

HTML:

```
...

</ul>

<form class="form-inline">
   <input class="form-control mr-sm-2 search-input" type="search" placeholder="Zoeken..." name="search" id="search">
   <button class="btn btn-search my-2 my-sm-0 " type="submit">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
   </button>
</form>


<ul class="navbar-nav">

...
```

CSS:

```
.form-inline{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.form-inline #search{
  width: 50%;
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2tya6v1j/2/)

Comment: Thanks, I got it moving now, But it is 100% in width. I can't figure out how to make it 50% in width and centred inside the navbar. Is that possible?

Comment: For some reason that does not work for me. The percentage works but even if I do `!important.` Behind the justify class is still doesn't work. Do you know the issue?

Comment: @Feudelcosine148 could you rephrase that please

Comment: @Feudelcosine148 You could take a look at the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2tya6v1j/2/)

Comment: I said It does not work for me. I have the exact same code in the snippet above. The width percentage works just fine, With that I mean; 70% width is 70% width. But `justify-content: center;` does not work for me. It just stays in place and does not actually go to the middle. Do you know what is causing this?

Comment: @Feudelcosine148 add `display:flex;` to `.form-inline`

Comment: I did, that does not work for some reason. Here is a picture for proof: https://imgur.com/a/RQ1eU

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to assign a min-width to your `.form-inline` and let the `.search-input` grow with flex-box:

```
.form-inline {
  min-width: 500px;
}
.search-input {
  flex-grow: 3;
}
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/aska-g/pen/NwNQPM)